# How we can connect HANA database using entity framework core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, hana

SAP HANA driver is available for .NET Core 2.1 but not .NET Core 3.1

Comment: ask this on answers.sap.com, this is not a programming question

Comment: @rajat, you got some solution for this?